# Laravel Passport Personal Access Token Expiration for some specific Token

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I want to set an expiry time for a token **at the time of token creation**.
I know that we can set an expiry time for all token in the following file:

```
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider
```

Using this code:

```
    public function boot() {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::routes();

        Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addMonths(6));
    }
```

But it will set that expiry time for all of the Personal Access Token and I want to set that expiry just for some specific token when I create by using:

```
    $user->createToken('User_'.$user['id'])->accessToken;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#token-lifetimes) solve that dilemma?

Comment: No, that will change expiry time for every token.